# Removing a block nested in a block via the local.xml file

Tags: magento, nested, block

I'm trying to use my local.xml file (where I do all my updates to the layout) to remove a block that is nested in another block.  I can easily remove a block via the <remove> tag, or using the unsetChild method, but I can't seem to remove a block that is nested in another block.

Here is the line of code I am trying to remove (located in the customer.xml file).  In particular, it's the block called "customer_account_dashboard_newsletter"

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_info1" as="info1" />
                <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_info2" as="info2" />
            </block>
        </reference>

    </customer_account_index>
```

I realize this doesn't work right now, but here is my starting point (located in my local.xml file):

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>customer_account_dashboard_newsletter</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referencing the wrong block. You have to reference the parent block of the block you want to remove. You are referencing the parent's parent block.

```
<customer_account_index>
  <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>customer_account_dashboard_newsletter</name></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

To unset a block inside another block you have to nest the references. For example:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>addtocart</name></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Also, sometimes the system doesn't recognize the block name, so you have to use the alias in the action.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to remove nested block, you should also nest references in `local.xml`, in your case the correct syntax would be:

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
            <remove name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" />
        </reference>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

But I noticed that the following line in `customer.xml`

```
<block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
```

doesn't have the effect of displaying block you want to remove. But the block is instead added inside `customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml` template, which is included by previous line in  `customer.xml`:

```
<block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
```

If you copy `customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml` to your theme you can remove the code that displays newsletter block on dashboard:

```
<?php if( $this->isNewsletterEnabled() ): ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Newsletter block from the Customer DashBoard you have to modify the file

app/frontend/yourtemplate/template/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml

and remove this block of code

```
<?php if( $this->isNewsletterEnabled() ): ?>
<div class="col-2">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-title">
            <h3><?php echo $this->__('Newsletters') ?></h3>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/manage') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <p>
                <?php if( $this->getIsSubscribed() ): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->__("You are currently subscribed to 'General Subscription'.") ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->__('You are currently not subscribed to any newsletter.') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.account.dashboard.info.extra')?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```